# Angularjs -Multiple Loop in a row using ng-repeat

Tags: javascript, arrays, angularjs

Guys I have two arrays to map in each rows column,so first loop in some column of the row successfully mapped with `ng-repeat` but I have other loop in the same row to map few column in the same row. So can I use `ng-repeat` here, how do I deal with this issue?

```
<tr ng-repeat="x in liveclaimdata"  ng-repeat="y in hxdata"   line-height="24px" id="row_{{$index+1}}" >
      
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
    <td id="{{$index+1}}_payer"></td>
    <td id="{{$index+1}}_payer"></td>
    <td id="{{$index+1}}_denials" ng-required="false" >{{x.denials}}</td>
    <td id="{{$index+1}}_low_reimb">{{x.low_reimb}} </td>
    <td id="{{$index+1}}_bundling">{{x.bundling}}</td>
    <td id="{{$index+1}}_payer_rating">{{x.payer_rating}}</td>
    <td id="{{$index+1}}_mr_request">{{x.mr_request}}</td>
    <td id="{{$index+1}}_appeal_percentage">{{x.appeal_percentage}}</td>
    <td id="{{$index+1}}_appeal_paid_percentage">{{x.appeal_paid_percentage}}</td>
 
    <td>Test  {{y.denials}} </td>
  
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
</tr>
```

Here `ng-repeat="y in hxdata"` is not working.

Live data array

```
0
:
$$hashKey
:
"object:61"
appeal_paid_percentage

:
"0"
appeal_percentage
:
"0"
bundling
:
"0"
cpt
:
"35301"
denials
:
"0"
low_reimb
:
"1"
mr_request
:
"0"
payer
:
"AETNA INSURANCE - TRS/KY"
payer_rating
:
"0"
row_num
:
"0"
1
:
$$hashKey
:
"object:62"
appeal_paid_percentage
:
null
appeal_percentage
:
null
bundling
:
null
cpt
:
"26370"
denials
:
null
low_reimb
:
null
mr_request
:
null
payer
:
"AETNA INSURANCE - TRS/KY"
payer_rating
:
null
row_num
:
"1"
__p
```

Similar structure in hx data

Comment: Is the length same?

Comment: rest of the column I need to fill up with hxdata ,I couldnt undetstood about the length

Comment: Can you please post some sample data and expected output

Comment: in liveclaimdata its array parsed as  out put as   0 0 0 3 0 0 0     json sample as {"status":"Success","data":[{"row_num":"0","payer":"AETNA INSURANCE - TRS\/KY","cpt":"35301","denials":"0","low_reimb":"1","bundling":"0","payer_rating":"0","mr_request":"0","appeal_percentage":"0","appeal_paid_percentage":"0"},

Comment: @RAJMOHAN Please add liveclaimdata array... & ... hxdata array

Comment: Please post it in question itself, with data for liveclaimdata, hxdata and the result you expect in html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on my understanding about the problem, you have related data in 2 arrays and you want to use `ng-repeat` to paint it.

Update (remove second ng-repeat)

```
<tr ng-repeat="x in liveclaimdata"  ng-repeat="y in hxdata"   line-height="24px" id="row_{{$index+1}}" >
```

to

```
<tr ng-repeat="x in liveclaimdata" line-height="24px" id="row_{{$index+1}}" >
```

and

Update (use the index to iterate over second array)

```
<td>Test  {{y.denials}} </td>
```

to

```
<td>Test  {{hxdata[$index].denials}} </td>
```

Answer (score 0):

This can be solved in another methode.by creating a function in $scope at contoller constructor

```
$scope.livedatamapping=function(response){   
                     $.each(response.data, function(key, value){    
                             var row = parseInt(key)+1;   
                       $('#'+row+'_appeal_paid_percentage').html(value.appeal_paid_percentage);
                       $('#'+row+'_appeal_percentage').html(value.appeal_percentage);
                       $('#'+row+'_bundling').html(value.bundling);
                       $('#'+row+'_denials').html(value.denials); 
                       $('#'+row+'_low_reimb').html(value.low_reimb);
                       $('#'+row+'_mr_request').html(value.mr_request); 
                       $('#'+row+'_payer_rating').html(value.payer_rating);
                         $scope.edidataLoader=false;
                       //$scope.claimdataLoader=false;
                 }); 
    }
```

and then map each value to the html mapper.Thats it